# Passport JWT Express Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have Express as backend and am trying to add authentication using Passport.js.
I want to authenticate by password only - and a unique password located in /config/main named key:

I can generate JWT by sending a POST request via /authenticate,
But I cannot access the app using that JWT and I am getting ERROR 401 with Unauthorized written in Postman.
My files :

passport.js

```
   var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;  
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

var config = require('./main');
var pass = config.key;
// Setup work and export for the JWT passport strategy
module.exports = function(passport) { 

var opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
// opts.issuer = "accounts.examplesoft.com";
// opts.audience = "yoursite.net";
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
        if (jwt_payload.key === pass) {
            return done(null, password);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
            // or you could create a new account
        }
    }));
};
```

app.js

```
 // Initialize passport for use
app.use(passport.initialize());  
// Bring in defined Passport Strategy
require('./config/passport')(passport);  
var mainConfig = require('./config/main');

var key = mainConfig.key;
var pass = mainConfig.password;
// Authenticate the user and get a JSON Web Token to include in the header of future requests.
router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {  

        var token = jwt.sign({
   key:'pass'
}, mainConfig.secret, { expiresIn: '24h' });
          res.json({ success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token });

// Enable CORS from client-side
app.use(function(req, res, next) {  
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});
router.get('/home', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res) {  

});

// Set url for API group routes
app.use('/react', router);
```

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know so I could improve my code and go further with my website. I am new to authentication feature, so please explain what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it!
The problem was that the response I  got was:

{
  "success": true,
  "token": "JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJrZXkiOiJwYXNzIiwiaWF0IjoxNDg0NDE1MzA4LCJleHAiOjE0ODQ1MDE3MDh9.Wb00qRygYnrpFTx2zs6o037i3UNiwRtmrrXFVhVYM04"
}

and I copied and pasted the token without the JWT beginning